# How do you get a simple logo to look crisp after compression for Twitter/Facebook profile pictures?

Tags: inkscape, gimp, logo, raster, compression

Being a complete novice at this but having tried many methods, I cannot get my logo to look crisp in my Twitter or Facebook profile pictures. It looks fine in Instagram.

I have been dabbling in GIMP and Inkscape to generate a simple  logo for my social media accounts. In my ignorance I first made a raster logo by tracing a picture in GIMP (pictured).
[image: raster version drawn in GIMP]

This worked out fine for Instagram (maybe because the size of the canvas, 1080 px sqaure, was the same as Instagram preferences?). After resizing the image as per Twitter/Facebook recommendations and trying both PNG and JPG uploads, it looks terrible in both at thumbnail size, particularly in the phone versions.

I've tried a bunch of different things to solve this (thanks to this fab forum and a few youtube tutorials): changing pixel density, changing export quality, changing file type, using filters, e.g. Gaussian blur, making it transparent, making it white background, etc...

I redrew it (roughly) as a vector in Inkscape using the bezier pen tool (pictured below). This was an experiment to see if having a vector version would solve the problem. It didn't, it still looks awful after uploading it at the recommended pixel dimensions, trying both PNG and JPG. It looks extremely pixelated as the thumbnail on a phone.

[image: Vector version drawn in Inkscape]

I'd be happy to start again but I don't know where to start. What do I need to do to create a black and white logo which compresses well in Twitter and Facebook profile pictures?

Comment: Pixels will **always** appear on curves and angles.

Comment: You could try turning off antialiasing when saving from svg to png, and reduce it to only use 2 colors (black and white) in the file's bit depth.
But in the end, it depends upon what Facebook does with your file, and the only thing that would fix it, would be getting the company to do something different with images uploaded to their site.

Also, if you upload the file in the exactly correct size, it might not require any resizing, and in theory could stay sharp (unmodified).

Comment: Yes, I have come to realise pixels will always appear. I just want my logo to look as good as other people are able to achieve.

Comment: I tried reducing it to 2 colours, which made it have very jagged edges. And I guess that turned off the antialiasing along with it? If my understanding of antialiasing is right. I had been uploading the correct size images, well what Facebook/Twitter recommend anyway, but the size of the thumbnail (which is where my problem lies) is tiny. I've got reasonably close to what I want in the end by exporting in jpg, reducing quality to about 50%, using a slight gaussian blur and an artistic 'cartoon' blur. Thanks for your help.